# PowerBI Dax Query - Match a Value and get its Maximum Value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to match the value in Column1 of one table with another and get the maximum value of column2.

For Example I have two tables,

Table 1

```
Col1 Col2
AA   17  
AA   20
AB   10
AB   21
```

Table 2

```
Col1 Col2
AA   ?
AB   ?
```

I want my output to look like this,

```
Col1 Col2
AA    20
AB    21
```

I have tried,

> Col2 = Max(Table1[col2])

but it didn't help. Thanks. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following DAX:

```
Col2 = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Table1[Col2]),
    FILTER(
        Table1,
        Table1[Col1] = Table2[Col1]
    )
)
```

Result:

[image: result]